# Extract .rar file using Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, zip, rar

I need to extract all type of archived file like .zip, .rar using java.

Comment: Sure, but RAR file is not a ZIP file. You can tell the difference by the different file extension.

Comment: okay, you are right. It's possible to unrar the .rar files in java

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `*.zip, *.jar` and `*.gz` using java inbuilt library called `GZIPInputStream`.

If you want to extract `.rar` then you have to use `junrar` library